# Is libgdx usable for 2d games?

Tags: java, android, windows, libgdx

Does anyone have experiences with libgdx that it works good with 2d graphics? 
I'm planning to use it for an Android/windows game, but i'm not sure if it's a good choise if i'm making a 2d game. Is there maybe a better 2d graphics solution you could recomend?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

libgdx works great for 2D. You can just use [SpriteBatch](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/SpriteBatch) if you all you want from libgdx is to draw on the screen. If you want a little more structure (you probably do), you can also work with the 2D scene graph, [scene2d](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/scene2d). When using scene2d, you create [`Actor`](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/Actor.html)s and add them to the [`Stage`](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/Stage.html), and then libgdx calls their update, draw, and touchevent functions for you.

libgdx also includes [scene2dui](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/scene2dui) for your menus, and it's based on the same scene graph (buttons are subclassed from `Actor`, etc).

For help getting started with scene2d, I found this really helpful:
http://steigert.blogspot.com/2012/02/1-libgdx-tutorial-introduction.html

And last but not least, if you're looking to develop for Android *and* the desktop, there's no better way to go than libgdx because libgdx does this out of the box. (Note that this also makes development *so much easier* since you don't have to run your app through the emulator or a device for every little test run.)

EDIT: updated links

Answer (score 2):

Sure it can be used for 2D games. Try [this](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=libgdx%20&c=apps) search for examples.

I can recommend one of the best 2D engines for Android: [AndEngine](http://andengine.org)
It is free, open source, has a huge community, a lot of examples and tutorials and released applications in Google Play Market.

Comment: id like to add that libgdx is probably the more flexible and powerful engine. [Source](http://www.andengine.org/forums/off-topic/andengine-vx-libgdx-t2547.html) and [Source](http://thegreystudios.com/blog/?p=30)

Comment: After several months I've decided to switch my project from AndEngine to libgdx. Libgdx has a lot of pros e.g. amazing instant debugging on desktop.

Answer (score 1):

This is not classic tutorial it is demo game with source code written in libgdx 0.96+ using scene2d and actors, and also including box2d: http://minimaldevelop.com/blog/libgdx-scene2d-game-example-code

Answer (score 1):

while a lot of libgdx is tailored to 2d it in no way restricts you to 2d

here is an example of using 3D with GLES 2.0 shaders and a dynamics lib with libGDX
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W9lfjaaEO-Q